# Upgrading hotcakes to version 01.10.03

Tags: e-commerce, dotnetnuke, upgrade

I am trying to upgrading hotcakes to version 01.10.03 and received below errors.

```
Page Load Exception 

United Sport Apparel 
AssemblyVersion 7.3.2 PortalID 0 PortalName United Sport Apparel UserID -1 

AssemblyVersion:7.3.2
PortalID:0
PortalName:United Sport Apparel
UserID:-1
UserName:
ActiveTabID:106
ActiveTabName:JB - Start From Scratch
RawURL:/design-your-jacket/build-your-jacket-from-scratch
AbsoluteURL:/Default.aspx
AbsoluteURLReferrer:http://staging.unitedsportapparel.com/design-your-jacket/build-your-jacket-from-scratch
UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:56ee52bf-e2bd-49dd-879f-854e5bc20189
InnerException:Method not found: 'Hotcakes.Commerce.HotcakesApplication Hotcakes.Commerce.Extensions.HccAppHelper.InitHccApp(Boolean)'.
FileName:
FileLineNumber:0
FileColumnNumber:0
Method:DWSoftware.Modules.usa_jacket.View.AddProductToCart
StackTrace:
Message:
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Method not found: 'Hotcakes.Commerce.HotcakesApplication Hotcakes.Commerce.Extensions.HccAppHelper.InitHccApp(Boolean)'. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Hotcakes.Commerce.HotcakesApplication Hotcakes.Commerce.Extensions.HccAppHelper.InitHccApp(Boolean)'.
   at DWSoftware.Modules.usa_jacket.View.AddProductToCart(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Source:
```

We debugged the code and found that the call to initialized the hotcakes commerce web service is throwing the error from the method call HccAppHelper.InitHccApp , we have not customized anything there, and if we comment the code it is not throwing any error. The code is similar to what they described on the website, Please see the below for the code.

```
protected void AddProductToCart(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        char gender = 'M';
        if (radFemale.Checked) gender = 'F';

        // create a reference to the Hotcakes store
        //var HccApp = HccAppHelper.InitHccApp();
        // get an instance of the product to add
        //var product = HccApp.CatalogServices.Products.FindBySku("United");

        decimal insurance;
        decimal finalPrice = CalculatePrice(out insurance, true);//calculate the price of the custom jacket

        //product.IsUserSuppliedPrice = true;
        //product.MetaDescription = hf_sku.Value;

        string sizingValues =
            "<ul><li><h4>Jacket Sizing:</h4></li>" +
            SummaryListItem("Height", ddl_Height_Ft.SelectedItem.Text + "\" " + ddl_Height_In.SelectedItem.Text + "'", 0) +//SummaryListItem("Height", txt_Height_Ft.Text + "\" " + txt_Height_In.Text + "'", 0) +
                                                                                                                           //SummaryListItem("Weight", ddl_Weight.SelectedItem.Text + " lbs", 0) +//SummaryListItem("Weight", txt_Weight.Text + " lbs", 0) +
            SummaryListItem("Gender", gender.ToString(), 0) +
            SummaryListItem("Size", ddl_JacketSize.SelectedItem.Text, 0) +
            "</ul>";
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ask the helpdesk of the module creators? It's a commercial module that is outside the scope of the DNN core. Not much we can do here at StackOverflow I think because we don't have access to the code. If you're lucky the developer reads this, he is a member here http://stackoverflow.com/users/152726/will-strohl

Comment: @shobhana Are you saying that everything works if you comment
 out that line of code that calls InitHccApp?

Comment: Also, can you please give some context as to where and when that code is running?

Comment: If we comment the  out the the all calles to hcc methods the process is getting completed and it is not throwing any error.

Comment: The Code is running when we are adding product into the Cart.

Comment: Please see the link from the hotcakes resources which describe the process of adding product into cart https://hotcakescommerce.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204725889-Add-a-Product-to-Cart-Programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the additional information you've provided in the comments.  It's unclear as to why you get that specific error in your code.  The line of code you're mentioning as the cause shouldn't technically cause that error.

This may be an issue with the way the project is set-up in your environment, or with missing/outdated DLL references.  You should refresh those references, as discussed in the documentation below.

https://hotcakescommerce.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204725889-Add-a-Product-to-Cart-Programmatically

Specifically, it calls out the following DLL's that should be referenced, and those DLL's should match the version of Hotcakes installed on your site.

In addition, we decided to go the extra mile and create a very clean proof of concept project, based upon the documentation above.

https://github.com/HotcakesCommerce/AddProductToCartModule

Here's the code block that should interest you.

https://github.com/HotcakesCommerce/AddProductToCartModule/blob/master/Modules/AddToCartModule/View.ascx.cs#L115-L144

Also, here's the block of code in the project file that should be in yours as well.  Please note how the version numbers are shown in the path.

https://github.com/HotcakesCommerce/AddProductToCartModule/blob/master/Modules/AddToCartModule/AddToCartModule.csproj#L54-L61

This is verified to work as of this morning.

Comment: We are seeing an error that method "SaveOrderCookies" does not exist in SessionManager which is part of Hotcakes.Commerce while rebuilding the custom code using new dll.Please suggest now in new version 1.10.03 which method can be used instead of SaveOrderCookies.

Comment: You don't need to call that anymore.  That's why you don't see it in the documentation any longer.  It was only necessary in older versions.